# Avoid capturing entire regex expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

When using the Matcher class in Java, you can define capture groups to be added to the group array defined within the matcher. When I set the pattern and compile it in the matcher, I always get at least one element in the array, and I do not want anything to be captured at all.

```java
String pattern = "(?:\\s*(?:SHOW\\s+TABLES)\\s*;)";
//Example input would be 'SHOW TABLES;'
//The array that I get from this looks like this ["SHOW TABLES;"].
//The array that I want to get would look like this [].
```

Comment: Forgot the (double) quotes? Try adding more context here.

Comment: You *always* get the full match, no matter what. If you replace `(?:` with `(` at start, you'll get it a second time.

Comment: So there is no way to prevent the full match from being added to the group array?

Comment: Also in java you need to escape the backslashes. `\s` -> `\\s`

Comment: I actually do in the code lol. I forgot to copy the properly defined java expreession from this regex tester I am using online.

Comment: I do not see what problem you have. If you do not need the `.group(0)` value, just do not `.add()` it to the `List<String>`. Have a look at [this code](http://ideone.com/uqXAUl).

Comment: Try this online tester https://regex101.com/ - it will not only show immediately what your regex matches, but also explain WHY. (Of course in the tester you do *not* escape the `\` and `"` characters.)

Comment: So why you need a regex at all if you don't want to capture anything? What you are trying to do? Do you want to match only groups if they occur?

Comment: I didn't use the actual example I am working with. I wanted to simplify the code for the `CREATE TABLE` driver in my database by not having to account for the `group(0)` reference being the entire expression. Essentially, I wanted this query `CREATE TABLE table_name (col1,col2,col3);` to give me an array like this `[table_name,col1,col2,col3]` not like this`[CREATE TABLE table_name (col1,col2,col3);,table_name,col1,col2,col3]`. @stribizhev @m.cekeira

Comment: @CrinkleyCrewms any particular reason you can't simply start all your indexing into the matches at 1, instead of 0?

Comment: No real reason except making the code simpler. I know it sounds ridiculous, but when you look at it from my point of view having just recently started using regex I assumed there was a built in way to prevent the entire expression from being saved. After all this I feel like I asked a stupid question. I thought the answer would be as simple as me missing a character in my regex expression. @ProgrammerDan

Comment: Eh, don't sweat it. Every language's implementation of Regex has some built in "huh" to it, Java's no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex will always capture the entire expression. That means **.group(0)** will always index the entire matched expression.